# Apache http client ( post request ) size limitation issue in centos7

Tags: post, jetty, httpclient, multipartform-data, restlet

I am tring to send more than 2GB file data in http post payload (content-type:multipart/formdata) by apache http client, but not able to send it, Looks like size limit is there ( Sever been used **Internal Restlet HTTP server**), Can any of you help me here to how can i achieve this, Thanks.

Apache http client version : 4.5.5
Restlet Api version : 2.4.0

Restlet been configured to execute with "internal Restlet HTTP server connector", Server side its not been configured with any data related to multipart/form-data size limitation.

Code:

```java
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
ContentBody payload = (ContentBody) uploadData.getPayload();
HttpPost httpPost = createHttpRequest(fileKey, payload, uploadData.getMd5Checksum());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

cuckooResponse = getResponse( response);
httpPost.releaseConnection();
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add details about what version of Apache Http Client you are using, and what version of the Restlet you are using?

Comment: You might want to add how your have your Restlet configured as well, as multipart/form-data configurations on server side often have maximum file size limits configured.